# Connection Refused error while communicating in android via TCP sockets using hole punching

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am developing an android application, which has to do real time communication between two phones. There is a client and server running on both the phones and I have a central server with which the Public IP and Port of each are exchanged.Both the phones are listening to the central server for notifications.

Say both the phones receive each others public ip and port through the central server, Then on each of the phones I start the client followed by the server (This is because, it fails in the other order, since I am doing hole punching I use the same port for listening and sending).

The following is how I start the server and client

```
socket=new Socket();
try {
    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(<Port of this phone>));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
ClientThread clientThread=new ClientThread(<IP of the other phone>,<Port of the other phone>,socket);
clientThread.execute();

Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread(<IP of this phone>,<Port of this phone>));
serverThread.start();
```

This is the code for my server

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

private String serverIP;
private int serverPort;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public ServerThread(String serverIP,int serverPort){
    this.serverIP=serverIP;
    this.serverPort=serverPort;
}


public void run() {
    try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort));
             while (true) {
                // listen for incoming clients
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.d("serverstatus","Connected :)");
                if(connected)
                //then pass messages
                }
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("serverstatus","Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
  }
```

}

This is the code for my client

```
public class ClientThread extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
private String serverIP;
private int serverPort;
private Socket socket;

public ClientThread(String serverip,int serverport,Socket mySocket)
{
    serverIP=serverip;
    serverPort=serverport;
    socket=mySocket;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try {
        while(true)
        {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIP, serverPort));
            if(socket.isConnected())
            {
             //pass messages
            }
        }
        }
       catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("clientstatus","Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //try again
        ClientThread clientThread=new ClientThread(serverIP,serverPort,socket);
        clientThread.execute();
       }
   }
}
```

What is expected is, after the first connection attempt from phone1 to phone2 fails(since phone2's port is not open yet), phone1's port becomes open (because of the request to phone2) and then when phone 2 tries to communicate to phone1, it succeeds because phone1's port is now open and so will phone2's(because of the phone2's request to phone1).

Still it is showing Connection Refused everytime I try connecting, and then a 'socket closed' exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong, can someone help me with this.

Comment: 'Connection refused' usually doesn't indicate a firewall problem, and 'socket closed' only means that you closed the socket yourself and then continued to use it: a programming error on your part.

Comment: @ejp I have not closed the socket anywhere in code until connection is achieved, and the socket closed error is coming in the next trial to establish connection. (The first attempt shows connection refused)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried similar with OSx and iOS. I had a very simple C code on the server side listening for incoming connection, this was capturing the phone's  ip and the port number something like 172.39.33.23:44392 (basically even if your phone is connected with the wifi router, I was able to send data to this port from another device). But rather than tcp, you should try sending data with UDP to the captured ip and port with datagrams (Java) .

```
  public void sendUdpData()
  {

      String phone1Ip = "172.39.33.23";
      int phone1Port = 44392;

      try 
      {
          String commandString =  "Send this data";
          byte[] commnadByte = commandString.getBytes();
          DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(commnadByte, commnadByte.length,InetAddress.getByName(phone1Ip),phone1Port);
          DatagramSocket datagramSocket=  new DatagramSocket(phone1Port);
          datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
          datagramSocket.close();
      } 
      catch (UnknownHostException e1) 
      {

      }
      catch (SocketException e1) 
      {

      }
      catch (IOException e1) 
      {

      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sending with UDP, wouldn't  guarantee the packet reaching the other end right? And why is it not possible with TCP? I'm doubting that even though I'm using hole punching, the firewall is restricting at the server end.

Comment: I know UDP does not guarantee the packet will be send however, the point is that, that is why it is called UDP hole punching. UDP is faster compared to TCP, so trick is that you might wanna use a different communication for guaranteed delivery. (Something like post get). UDP is used for gaming , and skype is using UDP. I guess your  basic structure should be like phone 1 connect to your server gets the ip and port, then phone 2 connects and server gets it is ip and port then you pass these information with post and get, then phone 2 can send data to phone 1 with udp.